# Font size is not changing automatically in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In the old Photoshop I used to use Up and Down arrows to change the font size and it always changed as soon as I clicked on the button, but **now I need to confirm every change with pressing Enter**. How can I make it change automatically?

I've searched through the settings and no luck...

Answer (score 1):

CTRL (CMD) SHIFT < or >

Changes the font size with the text box size.

Found this on Adobe's InDesign forum...
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/975686
tested it in photoshop and it works.

Comment: Does not help really :( Drives me nuts.